Magento 2 : Change 'Shipping & Handling' label while print the order
I want to change the Label from 'Shipping & Handling' to 'Shipping Charges' while printing the pdf after order success.
Can anyone help

Thanks

Are PDF print from admin side or frontend side from customer?

Frontemd order success print by customer

hello dear you are overriding the below file.
vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Totals.php
